# Strange thing with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse a web page like the following

```
     <div id="block-info-advan" style="width: 760px;">
        <div class="content-0">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    1</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="435943">
                        <a>...</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-1">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    2</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="435632">
                        <a <...</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**If I use:**

```
test = soup.select(".nqTitle")
```

```
result: 2
```

**But why if I use:**

```
test = soup.select("body .nqTitle")
```

```
result: 1
```

or

```
test = soup.select("body")
test2 = test[0].select(".nqTitle")
```

```
result: 1
```

In the second code, I expect the result as 2.

Can anyone explain for me?

Thanks.

Comment: you're going to need to add a link to the html you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in two ways, none of which happened. Maybe it's because of data elsewhere in your HTML.

```
html = '''
<body>
<div id="block-info-advan" style="width: 760px;">
        <div class="content-0">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    1</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="435943">
                        <a>...</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-1">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    2</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="435632">
                        <a>...</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div></body>
'''
```

BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
test = soup.select(".nqTitle")
print (test)
test = soup.select("body .nqTitle")
print (test)
test = soup.select("body")
test = test[0].select(".nqTitle")
print (test)
```

Result:

```
[<p class="nqTitle" lawid="435943">
<a>...</a>
</p>, <p class="nqTitle" lawid="435632">
<a>...</a>
</p>]
[<p class="nqTitle" lawid="435943">
<a>...</a>
</p>, <p class="nqTitle" lawid="435632">
<a>...</a>
</p>]
```

SimplifiedDoc:

```
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
test = doc.selects('p.nqTitle')
print (test)
test = doc.selects('body>p.nqTitle')
print (test)
test = doc.select('body').selects('p.nqTitle')
print (test)
```

Result:

```
[{'class': 'nqTitle', 'lawid': '435943', 'tag': 'p', 'html': '\n                        <a>...</a>\n                    '}, {'class': 'nqTitle', 'lawid': '435632', 'tag': 'p', 'html': '\n                        <a>...</a>\n                    '}]
[{'class': 'nqTitle', 'lawid': '435943', 'tag': 'p', 'html': '\n                        <a>...</a>\n                    '}, {'class': 'nqTitle', 'lawid': '435632', 'tag': 'p', 'html': '\n                        <a>...</a>\n                    '}]
[{'class': 'nqTitle', 'lawid': '435943', 'tag': 'p', 'html': '\n                        <a>...</a>\n                    '}, {'class': 'nqTitle', 'lawid': '435632', 'tag': 'p', 'html': '\n                        <a>...</a>\n                    '}]
```

Comment: thank dagingsou, it work now like you sugesttion. In my first code i guest problem is i used "html.parser" not "lxml" like you